# Java - what is "@Override" used for?

Tags: java, syntax, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's “@Override” there for in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489974/whats-override-there-for-in-java)

I've never put "@Override" before a method until now.  I see some code examples with it, but I don't understand its utility.  I'd love some explanation.

Many thanks,

JDelage

Comment: Duplicate of [What's "@Override" there for in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489974/whats-override-there-for-in-java)

Comment: Just to clarify, you say "@Override before a class" - do you mean a method? Or are you actually referring to an @Override annotation on a class?

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why

Comment: Sorry - that's indeed a duplicate but I ran a search for @Override and didn't get anything.

Comment: hmm, [this search gives some results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+%40Override) (personally I don't care if it's a duplicate, the comment is just to provide a tipp for SO searches)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you can't annotate a *class* with `@Override`. This annotation indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a superclass.

You don't have to annotate overriding methods *but* if you use this annotation and your annotated method *does not* override a superclass method, then the compiler will generate an error message.

Answer (score 8):

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a superclass. If a method is annotated with this annotation type but does not override a superclass method, compilers are required to generate an error message.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

The case I like to explain its use is when overriding `equals`.

This will error because `equals` expects an `Object` parameter:

```
public class Foo{

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Foo f){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...Though I think it can be omitted on methods that really are overrides. I think that will produce a warning in *some* environments, but not an error.

Comment: It will error if you put `@Override` on a method that doesn't override anything. It definitely is not required, but helps the compiler help you.

Answer (score 5):

The best example - overriding `equals()`.

If you write a class like this:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public String bar;

    public boolean equals(Foo other)
    {
        return this.bar.equals(other.bar);
    }
}
```

then you've *overloaded* the equals method, rather than overriding `Object.equals` as was intended.

If you annotate the equals method with `@Override`, the compiler will give you an error stating (correctly) that you haven't overridden a superclass method.

In Java 6, you can use this for implementing interface methods too - this is handy when you're only adding a method to your class to satisfy some interface, and hence the compiler can check that it's required and alert you to the interface changing.

As with all annotations it's effectively a programmatic comment, but having the compiler check that your assumptions are (still) correct is very handy in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

It's there to express that you expect the method to be overriding a superclass method. It does come in handy when you make a mistake spelling the method name or give it the wrong parameters so that it does not override what you thought it was overriding.

Answer (score 1):

It's a conventional comment. Some compilers make sure that the function followed by @Override is actually an override... just a failsafe