# An use for Java's @override

Tags: java, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s “@Override” there for in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489974/whats-override-there-for-in-java)

Since Java 1.5 this annotation was incorporated to the language to be used on methods that overwrite a superclass methods.

Now, what changes in a method that uses this annotation to one that doesn't use it? Is this just convention?

Assuming, obviously, that both be methods that overwrite a method from its superclass...

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why

Answer (score 7):

`@Override` creates a compile-time check that a method is being overridden.
 This is very useful to make sure you do not have a silly signature issue when trying to override

> It not only makes the compiler check but also documents the
>   developer's intention.

if you override a method but don't use it anywhere from the type itself, someone coming to the code later may know the purpose. The annotation explains its purpose.

A good IDE will helpfully flag any method that overrides a method without `@Override`, so the combination of the two will help ensure that you're doing what you're trying to.

it also improves readability