# Difference between @override in Java and @decorator in Python

Tags: java, python, overriding, decorator

I read some documentation of it and realized that there appears to be a relationship between `@override` in Java and `@decorator` in Python.

Can someone explain the relationship in plain English?

I understand that functions in Python are first class object and functions can be parameter of another function.

How does this `@override` syntax in Java differ from decorators in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's "@Override" there for in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489974/whats-override-there-for-in-java)

Comment: Java `@Override` is a compiler annotation. Apart from a vague resemblance to the Python `@decorator` syntax, there is **no** other correlation between the two concepts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no relation between `@override` in Java and `@decorator` in Python.

`@override` in Java is an annotation which marks a method as *overwriting* another method. So when I extend a base class and I overwrite some method of it, I can annotate this method with `@override`. This has no real effect on my code, it is just a hint for the compiler. Like **Martijn Pieters** suggests, see [What's "@Override" there for in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489974/whats-override-there-for-in-java) for more.

`@decorator` in Python is a design pattern. A decorator can be attached to a method to extend its functionality. If a method is called, its decorators will be called before. You can use this for example to log information. I used it once in a project to enable caching.

The most comparable thing to a @decorator in Java would be to define an annotation which can act like a decorator or use a library like AspectJ. However, this is not part of the core Java language which simply doesn't know any decorator annotation. A decorator and an annotation are two different things.

Comment: Martijn, or Pascal?